# How do I change the number formatting in Pocket Planes?

Tags: pocket-planes

I've seen that some people have a `,` in their money display.

For example, others have `192,234` coins but I have `192234` coins. I tried reinstalling Pocket Planes, even turning sync of then uninstalling, I install it again then, and its the same problem. Here are some examples in photos:

This one has a `,` in the money (not my): 
[image]

This one hasn't got a `,` in the money (my one): 
[image]

I want my money to have a `,` (comma) in it. So it's easier to read. How can I do this?

Comment: Wild guess here, but is it perhaps using your system's country code to set its money format?

Comment: thanks!!! right!!! Your wild guess is right! thank you sooo much.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, you should write up your comment as an answer, so you can get your well deserved credit.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already in the comments, Pocket Planes uses your device's country/regional settings to determine how to display numbers. To change way numbers are formatted on your device you will need to change your country/regional settings accordingly.